# get $.height() of an Element with Images in it when Image maybe not loaded yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I insert some HTML code after a Ajax Call and in the Ajax-Callback I need the height of the added Div.
The problem is, in the HTML from the Ajax Call are elements like Images and other elements that have to be laoded first.

I did a simple example of the problem in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbwd663s/3/
As you can see when I add the code the console says 36, but if you click the div it says 242 (cause the image is loaded). Sometimes it works too if the image is allready in the cache, to test it reload the page with cleared cache.

What I need is something like `$(document).ready()` but only the elements that got called by ajax. Anyone have an idea how I could do that?

Comment: You should bind .load event to images and then u ll get the height, once the images are loaded.

Comment: @HarryBomrah I could solve my task in another way. But this problem still exists. For only images your solution sounds good. But in my case there were other stuff (there was an iframe in it that loads stuff via ajax (like a facebook button and if it has likes it gets higher)). Will it be even possible to listen when all is loaded when it is so hard nested?

Comment: is the iframe placed by you or some other script is doing that? Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div *").one("load", function() {
  alert($("div").height());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aravi_vel/qbwd663s/6/

Use the load function as suggested by Harry

This function will handle the other kind of elements that you have listed (iframe etc.)